# errors creating a delegate from UISplitViewDetail to master in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols, cs193p

SWIFT / IOS 8.2
I am trying to set my `CalculatorViewController` as the delegate target so I can get data - but I seem to be setting it wrong: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code:2)"

(in GraphView.swift)

```
protocol CalculatorViewDataSource: class {
    func calculateYForXEquals(sender: CalculatorViewController, currentX: CGFloat) ->CGFloat?
}

class GraphView: UIView {
    weak var calculatorViewDataSource: CalculatorViewDataSource?
    //...
}
```

(in GraphViewController.swift)

```
class GraphViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var graphView: GraphView! {
        didSet{
            graphView.calculatorViewDataSource = self.view.superview?.superview as CalculatorViewController
        }
    }
// ...
}
```

(in CalculatorViewController.swift)

```
class CalculatorViewController: UIViewController, CalculatorViewDataSource{
    // ...
}

func calculateYForXEquals(sender: CalculatorViewController, currentX: CGFloat) ->CGFloat? {
    return nil
}
```

Issues:

I get a crash with a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code:2)" error when I try to set the delegate in the GraphViewController... Any idea why?

I don't know how to get to the class from the `CalculatorViewController` level.
Here's the storyboard:

```
-> SplitViewController - NavigationController - (Master) CalculatorViewController
         I
     NavigationController - (Detail) GraphViewController
```

Comment: sorry for the many edits, I am still trying to get around stackoverflow.com & not exactly sure if I am doing it right / editing properly. Thanks for your patience, I really want to make the post more readable rest assured

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:

```
    var graphViewController: GraphViewController?

    private func setupSplitViewController() {
        let masterNavigationController: AnyObject? = splitViewController?.viewControllers.first
        graphViewController = masterNavigationController!.topViewController as? GraphViewController
        graphViewController!.graphView.calculatorViewDataSource = self
    }
```

Comment: if I add the provided code within my CalculatorViewController It compiles but I get a fatal error when launching (**graphViewController!.graphView.calculatorViewDataSource = self** `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`) I take it the graphViewController might be nil, now I get to look at the view lifecycle I guess...

Comment: You should call `setupSplitViewController` at `viewDidLoad()` in ViewController cases and `awakeFromNib` or `initWithCoder` for UIView cases.

Comment: I'm hacking at it from looking at the suggested solution it seemed something like - `graphView.calcDataSource = splitViewController!.viewControllers.first!.subviews.first as CalculatorViewController`  would work but I'm getting the same error. Thanks for the follow up.