# "unexpectedly found nil" - delegate assignment in subVC

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have been stuck on this for the past few days -

`graphView` is my UI Class instance - I declare my CalculatorViewDataSource protocol outside of the `GraphView` class, which contain `weak var calcDataSource: CalculatorViewDataSource?` in it.

in my GraphViewController, in the didSet{} of the graphView outlet I try to set the delegate to what I assume is an existing CalculatorViewController using the following code:

```
 if let vc = splitViewController?.viewControllers {
            println(vc)
            println(vc.count)
            if let fst = vc.first {
                println(fst.subviews)
                println(fst.subviews.first)
            }
        }
graphView.calcDataSource = splitViewController!.viewControllers.first!.subviews.first as CalculatorViewController
```

the code compile, but I crash with "unexpectedly found nil" when I get to the assignment of graphView.calcDataSource

(output)

`[<UINavigationController: 0x7b71bd10>]
1
nil
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

(storyboard)

```
SplitViewController - NavigationController - (Master) CalculatorViewController
     I
NavigationController - (Detail) GraphViewController`
```

- is the syntax or the assignment wrong?
- I am trying to delegate to the masterView of a UISplitView from the detail, should I try to set the delegate in the masterView? Does this assume the detail / graphView already exists? (this seem to be what ([errors creating a delegate from UISplitViewDetail to master in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528349/errors-creating-a-delegate-from-uisplitviewdetail-to-master-in-swift)) hints at)

========

## SOLVED!

I worked around this issue by working from inside prepareForSegue
(with a storyboard segue on button called "Show Graph")

```
//CalculatorViewController.swift:
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue!.identifier == "Show Graph") {
        var yourNextViewController = (segue!.destinationViewController as UINavigationController)
        var detail = yourNextViewController.viewControllers[0] as GraphViewController
        var tempview = detail.view // FORCES THE VIEW object into existence, without this it will compile, but next line will crash at runtime (graphView nil)
        detail.graphView.calcDataSource = self
    }
}
```

note that **`var tempview = detail.view`** is critical here, despite not being used. I understand as it setting up the view and outlet..

Comment: Unwrap all the optionals, don't use `!` especially when debugging. Also log your splitViewController, the first viewController, etc. to see if it's even there or how many are there. Printing is your friend

Comment: how do I properly log the VCs? overload didLoad() with print()? how do I do that for VCs created via storyboard like the splitViewController?

Answer (score 0):

How to (safely) unwrap optionals:

```
graphView.calcDataSource = splitViewController!.viewControllers.first!.subviews.first as CalculatorViewController

if let vc = splitViewController?.viewControllers {
    println(vc)
    if let fst = vc.first {
        println(fst.subviews)
        println(fst.subviews.first)
    }
}
```

Comment: assuming the if block is before the assignment (to get the output)